# Is it possible to have a compact abelian $U(1)$ lattice gauge theory on a non-compact manifold?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, lattice-gauge-theory

We have a compact lattice gauge theory if we let $A_{i}(n)\in[-\pi,\pi]$, and if we identify $A_{i}(n)\sim A_{i}+2\pi$. A simple lattice gauge theory in 2+1D then has an action

$$S=\sum_{x}1-\cos(F_{\mu\nu})$$

Here, the compactness of the gauge field is provided by the periodicity of the action with respect to $A$. It has nothing to do with the topology of the manifold (spatial space) that the theory is defined on.

As far as I understand, compactness of the gauge field has nothing to do with the compactness of the manifold that the theory lives in.

So, is it really correct that I can define a lattice gauge theory where gauge fields are compact but the lattice is non-compact (e.g. euclidiean flat lattice)?

If this is the case in lattice gauge theories, then is it also the case in continuum theories?

Comment: Yes, why do you ask?

Comment: what do you mean by why?